# Flashing from recessed exterior door on concrete?

Tags: doors, deck, flashing, threshold

Old house, with poorly installed exterior door on top of renovated old garage which leads to deck. I'm installing a waterproofing system, and I could probably flash in almost every place but not sure how I would in the door threshold area.  I assume most properly-installed (or preassembled doors) flash as part of the installed threshold and the overhang of the door install. I don't have this.  Don't think they make a sill pan or threshold (biggest I've seen is 7 13/16) that would fit this. Do I have any options to flash my deck at this threshold or do I have to do the non-flashing-but-not-watertight install method of the waterproofing system?

[image: Threshold]
[image: Dimensions]
[image: Profile]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else wondering about this: Trex Rainescape (what I installed) has an installation method against non-flashed brick (see the manual).  You use butyl tape, caulk, and a 'wall flash' rubberized flashing.  Yes there is no flashing with this method (which is pretty standard on brick) but if you put enough tape, caulk and flashing (and install the trough material with an overlap) you can get it pretty waterproof.